# Upper bounds for the least $a$ in $p \nmid x^3-a$

Tags: number-theory

Are there any bounds for $a$ when for all $x$, $p \nmid x^3-a$ and $p$ is a prime number?

There have been numerous studies on the [smallest quadratic non residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Least_quadratic_non-residue).

However, are there such bounds for cubes as well?

It is known that no such $a$ exists when $p-1$ is coprime to $3$.

However, what happens if $p-1$ is not coprime to $3$?

Because of [Thue`s Lemma](http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvMy8yL2QzYjEzOGM0ODE3YzYwZGU4NGFmOTEwZDc0ZGNhODRjOGMyMzZlLnBkZg==&rn=dGh1ZS12NC5wZGY=), there exists $x \equiv ky \pmod p$ where $x,y$ has a absolute value less than $\sqrt {p}$ and $k$ is a number coprime to $p$.

If we set $k$ as a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) of $p$, and if all numbers smaller than $\sqrt {p}$ was not such a $a$, it would be a contradiction.

My Question is Thus: For $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ is it true that $a<2\sqrt [ 3 ]{ p }$?

This seems to be true, but I cannot prove it, nor do I have any idea how to solve it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The phrase "If $n$ was $3$" seems a typo (or misplaced) since there is no other mention of $n$ in the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $3 \mid p-1$ then let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Write $a=g^k$ then 
$$x^3 \equiv g^k \mod{p} \Leftrightarrow 3 |k$$

So the question you ask is the following: Find the smallest positive integer $a$ which is in  the set
$$A:=\{ g^k | 3 \nmid k \}$$

Therefore, the order of magnitude of primitive roots [link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Order_of_magnitude_of_primitive_roots) give you some upperbounds. But since $A$ can contain (especially when $p-1$ has many divisors) many non-primitive roots, it is likely that a better upperbound can be found, but I don't see any obvious one.

Comment: Sorry, but don't you mean $3|p-1$?

Comment: The OP dispenses with the case $3$ coprime to $p-1$ since cubing is then an automorphism on the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ (and thus every nonzero residue is a cube).

Comment: @ChadShin Ty fixed it. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @N.S. So is it unlikely that $a<2\sqrt [ 3 ]{ p }$ can be proved?

Comment: @ChadShin It is not clear to me.... Note that $A$ has roughly $2/3p$ elements and missing  $1/3 p$ elements, but those elements cannot really be anything...Might be better to ask the question on MathOverflow....

Comment: @N.S. Can I ask this question on Math Overflow? I thought that you could only ask highly professional questions there.

Comment: @ChadShin I am not an expert in the field, but this question looks closer to a research level question than to homework, so it is likely appropriate there. If you ask it, don't forget to link this question in your post, and mention that it was not answered here.